# How to get value of input text field in select box option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used an custom select box with a search input and a button of "add".this input field act like search and searches regarding the value in dropdown option . but when the value don't match with the values then i need that on click of that add button the value of this field should add in the option and also act as selected value of the dropdown . please help ...

thanx..

```js
$(function() {
        $(".standards").customselect();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://classvita.com/admin/res/javascripts/jquery-customselect.js'></script>
<link href='http://classvita.com/admin/res/stylesheets/jquery-customselect.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<select name='standard' class='custom-select standards'>
    <option value=''>Add Particular</option>
    <option value='1'>abc</option>
   <option value='2'>aabc</option>
   <option value='3'>abbc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add your complete code till now. We dont know what is your add button and other details

Comment: just click on add particular , there is a dropdown and in last it have an add button .. and its code is in linked js file

Comment: can you show us what is the code for Add New Item? is it generated by plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution, but this is a way to reach your solution.

```
<select name='standard' class='custom-select standards' id="SelectList">  //add id attribute
<option value=''>Add Particular</option>
<option value='1'>abc</option>
<option value='2'>aabc</option>
<option value='3'>abbc</option>
</select>
```

here is how you can add a select-list Item:

JS:

```
var html = "<option value=\""+ ListItemNumber +"\">"+ TheSearchTerm +"</option>";
$('#SelectList').append(html);   //binding the html
$('#SelectList').val(ListItemNumber);   //Select the ListItem
```

Hope this helps you.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `click` event on your `Add New Item` button and on click of that button you should create a new option and add to your `custom` select as follows,

```
$(document).on('click', "#add_new_button_id", function(){
  //get the value from input text
   var typedValue = $("#input_id").val();
  //create option on click and add to your custom select
  $('.custom-select').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", typedValue).text(typedValue));
});
```

Comment: @AnkitJain post your changes and where it failed?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('change','select[name="standard"]',function(){

var pid = $(this).val(); //grabbing the current value of the select.
if(check here if pid lies in some sort of arrays ,values etc)
{
$('select[name="standard"]').append('<option value="'+pid+'">'+pid+'</option>');

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
        $(".standards").customselect();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://classvita.com/admin/res/javascripts/jquery-customselect.js'></script>
<link href='http://classvita.com/admin/res/stylesheets/jquery-customselect.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<select name='standard' class='custom-select standards'>
    <option value=''>Add Particular</option>
    <option value='1'>abc</option>

   <option value='2'>aabc</option>
   <option value='3'>abbc</option>
</select>
```